# Achar o ângulo entre 2 vetores em 3d

Tags: lua

Eu quero os ângulos X Y Z entre os 2 vetores

Para fazer uma linha entre eles dois.

```
math.atan2(t2.y - t1.y, t2.x - t1.x) * 180 / math.pi)-90
```

Esse foi a conta que usei pra descobrir o Z, mas os outros eu não consigo fazer, o X e Y.

O de tamanho é

```
C.Size=Vector3.new(0.2,math.sqrt((t2.z-t1.z)^2+(t2.y-t1.y)^2+(t2.z-t1.z)^2),0.2)
```

Exemplo:

Fiz no paint porque tenho que ir rápido.

Preciso descobrir o ângulo para rotacionar a linha laranja entre os 2 pontos, os conectando pela mesma.

[image: cubo]

Comment: Só existe um ângulo entre dois vetores, não?

Comment: Você quer os ângulos da projeção do plano formado pelos dois vetores nos planos normais?

Comment: Mr Felix . Eu quero os angulos da projecao . pq é em 3d

Comment: Das projeções de cada vetor ou da projeção do plano formado pelos dois vetores?

Comment: Me desculpe eu n consigo responder pois sou meio iniciante em trigonometria e.e

Answer (score 4):

O tamanho (ou magnitude) de um vetor é calculado pela fórmula de Pitágoras, ou seja, a raiz quadrada da soma dos quadrados de cada componente do vetor.

O produto escalar de dois vetores é calculado como a soma dos produtos de cada componente, e o que ele representa é o produto do comprimento dos dois vetores com o cosseno do ângulo formado entre eles. Logo, ao dividir-se o produto escalar pelos tamanhos dos vetores, chega-se ao cosseno do ângulo.

Tendo o cosseno do ângulo, `math.acos(x)` vai te dar o ângulo em radianos. Essa função `acos` significa *arco-cosseno*, ou cosseno inverso.

Tendo o ângulo em radianos, `math.deg(x)` vai te dar o ângulo em graus. Essa função serve exatemente para converter radianos em graus.

Assim sendo, isso deve ser o que você quer:

```
function vetor3D(x, y, z)
    local v = {}
    v.x = x
    v.y = y
    v.z = z
    return v
end

function magnitude(v)
    return math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z)
end

function produto_escalar(a, b)
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z
end

function angulo(a, b)
    ta = magnitude(a)
    tb = magnitude(b)
    if ta == 0.0 or tb == 0.0 then
        return 0.0
    end
    return math.deg(math.acos(produto_escalar(a, b) / ta / tb))
end

# Teste
a = vetor3D(1, 0, 0)
b = vetor3D(0, 1, 0)
print(angulo(a, b))

c = vetor3D(1, 1, 1)
print(angulo(a, c))
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/BCulA7)

Observe que no final esse `angulo(a, c)` vai dar o ângulo entre uma das arestas do cubo e a diagonal. O programa exibe como saída para isso `54.735610317245` (em graus).