# Valores do sensor acelerômetro para graus decimais

Tags: java, android

Preciso pegar o valor de inclinação e declinação do celular no modo paisagem, porém os valores que preciso são em graus decimais, de -90 a 0 a 90 graus.
Tentei usar o acelerômetro, mas os valores desse sensor são de 0 a 10. Também tentei usar o magnetômetro, mas alguns celulares não tem esse sensor. Como posso obter esses valores usando somente o acelerômetro?

Código usando o acelerômetro:

```
package br.eng.itech.smarthipsometer_01;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;

    TextView textViewX;
    TextView textViewY;
    TextView textViewZ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewX);
        textViewY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewY);
        textViewZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewZ);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (accelerometer == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor acelerômetro não encontrado no dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }else {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        textViewX.setText(String.format("X: %.2f", sensorEvent.values[0]));
        textViewY.setText(String.format("Y: %.2f", sensorEvent.values[1]));
        textViewZ.setText(String.format("Z: %.2f", sensorEvent.values[2]));

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nota: não sou programador Android, então estou respondendo isso apenas com os conceitos de física e matemática adquiridos ao longo dos anos. Talvez seja adequado olhar a [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position#sensors-pos-orient) sobre o posicionamento do dispositivo, mas ela passa por uma matriz de rotação 3x3 para então achar os ângulos; ele também faz uso das leituras do acelerômetro e do magnetômetro

O sensor do tipo `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` vai retornar a força de aceleração em cada eixo (vide [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#table1)). Nesse tipo de sensor, o retorno é um vetor com 3 posições:

- `SensorEvent.values[0]`, força da aceleração no eixo X
- `SensorEvent.values[1]`, força da aceleração no eixo Y
- `SensorEvent.values[2]`, força da aceleração no eixo Z

Esses eixos são considerados conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: eixos de um dispositivo Android]

Note também que a aceleração está em m/s², conforme unidade base do SI (a unidade poderia estar em N (newtons) também, mas isso implica conhecer a massa do aparelho **e** de qualquer outra coisa anexada a ele, mas no final das contas essa massa pode ser desprezada e a única coisa que importa mesmo é a taxa de aceleração).

Quando o corpo está totalmente na vertical sem sofrer mudanças em suas posições, você terá o efeito da força da gravidade (no eixo Y, apontando para baixo) e a força normal em perfeito equilíbrio com a gravidade. Esse sensor não se importa com a força normal, então no final das contas você está medindo apenas a força da gravidade. Como estamos na Terra, a gravidade terá efeito de acelerar a [9,8 m/s²](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acelera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_gravidade). Por isso então que você tem a impressão de que os resultados são entre 0 e 10, qualquer que seja a posição.

Para você detectar que o celular está mais "deitado" do que "de pé", o componente da gravidade no eixo X deve ser significante do que o componente da gravidade no eixo Y. Mas ainda assim isso não será capaz de dizer o quão "paisagem" ou o quão "retrato" de fato está o celular. Para responder essa pergunta, é necessário entender também como se calcula Φ e Θ dessa questão aqui do [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2247039/506414). Vou reproduzir a imagem contina nessa questão abaixo para ficar melhor ilustrado:

[image: vetor no espaço 3D]

> Note que, no caso, o eixo que essa imagem considera "para cima" é o Z, e o eixo que "sai da tela de leitura" é o X. Essa é a representação mais clássica do espaço 3D; mas podemos reentender esses eixos de acordo com a orientação Android, e é isso que iremos fazer. Iremos considerar o eixo "para cima" como sendo o Y, e o eixo que "sai da dela" como o Z. Leve essa reinterpretação em consideração quando ler minhas explicações abaixo

No nosso caso, precisamos levar em consideração o valor de Θ para saber o quão inclinado o celular está. Quando o valor de Θ for 0 graus, o celular estará perfeitamente alinhado na vertical. Quando for Θ = 180 graus, ele estará de cabeça para baixo. Uma medida para verificar isso de maneira rápida é tirar o [cosseno](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosseno), pois `cos(0) = 1` e `cos(180) = -1`. O ângulo, portanto, pode ser considerado como um valor intermediário que podemos descartar. Ou então, se precisarmos muito dele, podemos usar a função [arco cosseno (`acos`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos-double-): dado o valor do cosseno, qual o ângulo que gera esse cosseno?

Note que `acos` retorna em radianos; para converter para graus, [leia esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184702/64969).

Para calcular o valor do cosseno de Θ precisamos da magnitude do vetor (hipotenusa) e de seu componente no eixo Y (cateto adjacente). [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172850/64969) mostra como achar a magnitude de um vetor em 3D. O componente no eixo Y é `SensorEvent.values[1]`. Então, para achar o cosseno da inclinação Θ, seria necessário o seguinte cálculo:

```java
float xPart = SensorEvent.values[0];
float yPart = SensorEvent.values[1];
float zPart = SensorEvent.values[2];

float magnitude = Math.sqrt(xPart*xPart + yPart*yPart + zPart*zPart);

float cosTheta = ypart/magnitude; // <== variável de nosso interesse
```

Em cima dessa informação, você pode tomar alguma decisão sobre se está paisagem ou retrato ou o que for. Note que não estou considerando aqui se o celular está "olhando para o chão" (rotação no eixo X), apenas a inclinação dele (rotação no eixo Z). A rotação no eixo Y é desprezível para o seu cálculo e creio que ela, puramente, não seja detectável apenas pela gravidade (talvez seja detectável no momento em que se rotaciona o eixo Y junto de outras rotações, mas ela de toda sorte é desprezível).

Se desejar mesmo o ângulo em graus, só fazer o seguinte:

```java
float thetaGraus = Math.acos(cosTheta) * 180.0/Math.PI;
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda! Resposta bem resumida, mas muito bem explicada. Consegui chegar no meu objetivo através da sua explicação.